# The convergence of $\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a+(-1)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Test the following series for convergence:
>   $$\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a+(-1)^n} , \quad a> 0.$$

I tried to use $$\frac{U_{n+1}}{Un}.$$
I get $$\frac{-n^a-(-1)^n}{(n+1)^a+(-1)^{n+1}},$$ 
but the limit is undefined.

$\dfrac{1}{(n+1)^a+(-1)^n}$
 is not decreasing, so I can't use Leibniz test.

Comment: it is a alternating series, will ratio test work here?

Comment: in $a\succ 0$, what does $\succ$ means?

Comment: If you cannot apply Leibniz directly: do a Taylor series expansion of the general term to two terms. Apply Leibniz to the first (now you can), and see what happens to the second term of the expansion (it should be positive). Convergence of the series will be determined by the convergence of the series of this second term.

Comment: "but the limit is undefined" - are you sure about that?

Comment: @Simply Beautiful Art:i mean (-1)^n,but when using Hospital'rule the limit is -1 ,and $$n\neq 1$$ i think

Answer (score 4):

Hint: Think of the sum as

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\left (\frac{1}{(2k)^a + 1} - \frac{1}{(2k+1)^a - 1}\right).$$

Comment: This is how I would have suggested ... (+1)

Comment: I tried but am not good enough with mathjax. And had to give up!   +1.

Comment: @OscarLanzi One need not use mathjax to analyze math problems.  Paper and pencil should suffice.

Comment: Not the analysis.  Rendering the result here is the problem.

Comment: @OscarLanzi xD Just takes practice.

Comment: Note that this approach allows you to find the closed form of the sum as well.

Comment: @simplybeautifulart What is the closed form solution here?

Comment: @MarkViola Not sure for general $a$, but if there were a closed form for a particular $a$, this should be the approach.  If you wish, you apply PFD to the fractions over $\mathbb C$ and get a closed form in terms of Hurwitz zeta functions, assuming $a\in\mathbb N$.

Comment: @simplybeautifulart Ah, you're restricting $a$ to positive integers.  The series converges for $a>1/2$.   The interesting part of this analysis are cases for which values of $a\in(1/2,1]$.

Comment: @MarkViola I doubt on closed forms there, except at $a=1$.

Comment: @zhw:thank you for the suggestion,can i ask how did you separate the general term in two?

Comment: @mezzaluna  I didn't separate, I joined the first and second terms together, then joined the third and fourth terms together, ....

Answer (score 2):

Observe that

$$\sum_{n=2}^m \frac{(-1)^n}{n^a + (-1)^n} = \sum_{n=2}^m \frac{(-1)^n\,[n^a - (-1)^n]}{[n^a + (-1)^n]\,[n^a - (-1)^n]} \\ =  \underbrace{\sum_{n=2}^m \frac{(-1)^n\,n^a}{n^{2a} - 1}}_{\text{converges for }\, a \,> \, 0} -  \underbrace{\sum_{n=2}^m \frac{1}{n^{2a} - 1}}_{\text{converges for }\, a \,> \, 1/2} $$

Convergence of the first sum on the RHS can be established by the alternating series test.  The second sum can be compared with a p-series that converges if $a > 1/2$ and diverges if $a \leqslant 1/2$. Hence, the original series with $a > 0$ diverges for $0 < a \leqslant 1/2$ and converges for $a > 1/2$.

Answer (score 0):

The infinite sum can be expressed as the sum of two infinite sums, one for odds and one for evens. Further I will assume that all $n$ are positive. I will explain how there is a similar problem with an equivalent solution at the end.

NOTE by original author: This solution is incorrect, I'll work on it. To separate into two series, the original must be convergent.

\begin{equation}
\sum\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a+(-1)^n}=\sum\frac{1}{(2n)^a+1} - \sum\frac{1}{(2n+1)^a-1}~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~(1)
% if someone has a better way to space that eqn number, please do
\end{equation}

These series can show convergence if a>1 when compared to similar series not including the constant $\pm1$ using the limit comparison test. The limit comparison test states that if the limit of the ratio of the two series is non-zero and finite, then the two series must both diverge or both converge. The limits are evaluated using L'Hopital's rule.

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n)^a}{(2n)^a+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n^{a-1}}{n^{a-1}}=1
$$

similarly for the other series.
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n+1)^a}{(2n+1)^a-1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n+1)^{a-1}}{(2n+1)^{a-1}}=1
$$

Both series $\sum(2n)^{-a}$ and $\sum(2n+1)^{-a}$ can be shown to converge for $a>1$ by integral test. So the both RHS series in Eq $1$ are convergent and is equal to the difference of two finite numbers, which means your series is convergent for $a>1$.

As far as using $n<0$ any $n^a$ can be expressed as $(-k)^a$ for $k>0$. Then using Euler's identity for $-1$, 
$$
(-k)^a = (e^{i~\pi/2}k)^a = e^{ia~\pi/2}k^a
$$
and the original sum can be expressed as follows for some complex constant, $C$ and it would cancel in the limit calculation
$$
\sum_{k>0}\frac{(-1)^k}{Ck^a+(-1)^k}
$$

Just realized I was too slow.

Comment: The splitting into the two series is only valid if both series converge.  And the individual series converge for $a>1$ as you mentioned.  However, the original series converges for $a>1/2$ and diverges elsewhere.  So, conclusion is incomplete at best.

Comment: I only answered since I was confident in my answer. Should I remove my answer?

Comment: Well, I think the answer needs to be modified.  Note that $$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=2}^{2N}\frac{(-1)^n}{n^a+(-1)^n}&=\sum_{n=1}^N \left(\frac{1}{(2n)^a+1}- \frac{1}{(2n+1)^a-1}\right)\\\\
&=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(2n+1)^a-(2n)^a-2}{((2n)^a+1)((2n-1)^a-1)}\tag1
\end{align}$$

Then, seeing that the numerator on the right-hand side of $(1)$ can be written as $(2n+1)^a-(2n)^a-2=-2+O(n^{a-1})$ as $n\to \infty$ while the denominator on the right-hand side of $(1)$ can be written as$((2n)^a+1)((2n-1)^a-1)=O(n^{2a})$.  We can conclude that the series converges for $a>1/2$ and diverges otherwise.

Comment: I think you might have a typo, the numerator appears to be order $n^a$. I had that but I've never seen a direct proof of showing that power order was sufficient if it's not polynomial order, and I couldn't see it myself as I was using the limit comparison test. In addition (using your orders), it seems odd since we could compare to any series $\sum\mathcal{O}(n^{a-1})/\mathcal{O}(n^{2a}) = 1/\mathcal{O}(n^{a+1})$ to conclude that it converges for $a>0$

EDIT: just thought of the case of sums of non integer power functions, it's easy and that's why I haven't seen it elsewhere.

Comment: Why do you believe that the numerator is $O(n^a)$?  It isn't.  $$\begin{align}(2n+1)^a-(2n)^a-2&=(2a)^n\left(1-\frac{1}{2n}\right)^a-(2n)^a-2\\\\&=(2n)^a-a(2n)^{a-1}+O(n^{a-2})-(2n)^a-2\\\\&=-2+O(n^{a-1})\end{align}$$

Comment: Only looked at (2n+1)^a, sorry

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62657/discussion-between-orion-yeung-and-mark-viola).